# Missing cache items [via phpfastcache] using Server Side Events

Tags: php, caching, phpfastcache

I'm using Server-Sent Events, to print messages for user.

In infinite loop, every 10 seconds I check if there is any new item in cache to broadcast:

```
$messages_to_broadcast = $this->_cache->getItemsByTag('inbox_message');
foreach ($messages_to_broadcast as $key => $_message) {
    $_message = $_message->get();
    if($_message->recipient == $this->_user_id || $_message->recipient == 0){
        if(!is_null($html = \CRM\Engine\MessagingService::getMessageToBroadcast($_message)))
        {
           echo "event: $_message->type \n";
           echo "data:{\n";
           echo "data:\"message_html\": \"$html\" \n";
           echo "data:}\n\n";
           $this->send_keepalive = false;
           $this->_cache->deleteItem($key);
        }
    }
}
```

At irregular intervals, there is event, which save message to cache:

```
$_cache_this = self::$_cache->getItem("message_".$_message->id);
if(!$_cache_this->isHit()){
    $_cache_this->set($_message)
        ->expiresAfter(600)
        ->addTag('inbox_message');
    self::$_cache->save($_cache_this);
}
```

The problem is that while I check in infinite loop for new items in cache, I get empty array. When I reload page, or browser reconnect to Server Side Events stream, item appears in cache. Is there any `flush` method I'm missing here?
I'm using `files` as cache method.

```
\phpFastCache\CacheManager::setDefaultConfig(array(
    "path" => DIR_TMP
));
global $cache;
$cache = \phpFastCache\CacheManager::getInstance('files');
```

Answer (score 2):

In a loop, you have to use the `detachItem` method of PhpFastCache to force it to get the right value.

Here an example:

```
while (1) {
    $cache = $this->cacheService->getCache();
    if (null !== $cache) {
        try {
            $item = $cache->getItem('my_key');
            if ($item->isHit()) {
                echo "event: message\ndata: $item->get()\n\n";
            }
            $cache->detachItem($item);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException | PhpfastcacheInvalidArgumentException $e) {
            $this->logger->error(
                'There has been an error when getting cache item: '
                .$e->getMessage().' - '.$e->getFile().' - '.$e->getLine()
            );
        }
    }

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    if (connection_aborted()) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

I open a issue to ask more doc here: https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/issues/687

Answer (score 1):

Phpfastcache is storing (the exact definition is "caching" in fact) the cache item statically in the cache backend object. So effectively you'll need to release the object using `detachItem()` method or `clear()` to empty the cache.

As described on [this issue](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/issues/687), I'll update the Wiki coming soon to clarify that behaviour for perpetual CLI scripts.

Comment: This is probably issue solver. Although the project where I had this problem is long dead. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's a while you've asked this, but usually you can only grab the items in cache by tag, haven't seen a method that let's you get all cache entries.

`$entries = $cache->getItemsByTag('inbox_message')`

`$entries` will now hold all your items.

Have a look here:
https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/blob/final/docs/examples/tagsMethods.php
where you can see a complete example on usage.